# Draw Image with Background color using PDF BOX library

Tags: java, pdfbox

Using below code I am able to create a pdf doc with an image but I would like to place the image on top of an background colour, I tried bit on my side but not able to achieve it can any one help me in achieving this:

```
public class SimpleTable {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
          //Loading an existing document

          PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();  

          PDPage my_page = new PDPage();
          //Retrieving the page
     doc.addPage(my_page);

          //Creating PDImageXObject object
          PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile("D:\\QRCode.png",doc);

          //creating the PDPageContentStream object
          PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(doc, my_page);
          PDImageXObject
          //Drawing the image in the PDF document
          contents.drawImage(pdImage, 70, 250);
          contents.setNotStrokingColoar(Color.RED);

          System.out.println("Image inserted");

          //Closing the PDPageContentStream object
          contents.close();     

          //Saving the document
          doc.save("D:\\QRCode.pdf");

          //Closing the document
          doc.close();

       }



}
```

Note: the background-colour occupancy will be same as image size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this before drawing your image and remove the fill that is in your current code:

```
contents.setNotStrokingColoar(Color.RED);
contents.addRect(70, 250, pdImage.getWidth(), pdImage.getHeight());
contents.fill();
```

Be aware that a background color will make it more difficult to scan the QR code because there'll be less contrast.

Comment: after drawing rectangle since we are drawing image on same space over it , it seems it is getting overridden hence it is not working.  And even the image name is QR code in this case and I am not using an QR code image i am using an image with dark white text and light white background.

Comment: Thanks Tilman this would for some other image type which i think can be work around for me .

Comment: If the image is not transparent then it won't work. If you want to make your image transparent, then load it, copy into ARGB, then go through the pixels and set all white pixel to transparent. Of course then you could also just set the color you want. Btw what's really good is to convert barcodes into vector graphics, there are a few answers here.

Comment: *"If the image is not transparent ..."* - in that case you can alternatively draw the red rectangle *over* the image using the blend mode **Darken**.